# Resetting virtualbox machine causes "iPXE (http://ipxe.org) E2:00.0 E200" to appear

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, windows-11

I'm installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine but just got a weird, extremely rare error from VirtualBox instead of the usual VB BIOS boot screen.

I can't use anything to recover VirtualBox because VBox would keep up with the bootup error. How can I get out of this without recreating my VM?

> Hello [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john), my VBox is installled to a write-protected folder and I am not an administrator on my Windows host, so I am unable to remove my installation without admin permission. Any other ideas (in the box below)? I think it can still happen, but it only happened when I press <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Can you COPY the machine folder to another location.   Then uninstall VBOX, restart, and install it again. Then copy your machine folder back.

Comment: I have the same problem after installing some windows update and reboot!